# How to display BLOB image and other information from MySQL table on the same JSP page from a servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, blob

I have a table registration table with the profile image,name and other info. I also have a servlet which retrieves the infromation from the table and "adds" it to the **ArrayList**. Works well with string and other datatypes, but I'm at loss for how to implement the same for **BLOB**. 
      I have passed the ArrayList with everything except the BLOB and works well. But I also implemented a Scriptlet with Image alone but now it shows only the image and does not show the ArrayList information.

Comment: This question should have code that you have written so far and specific problem you are facing. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

What type is the retrieved blob? I guess it is byte[]? how you do it?

There is no actual need to implemented this with BLOB. If you don't have a restriction you better implemented with a base64 String, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930516/jsp-javascript-display-byte-as-image/47962868#47962868)

but if you insist to go with the blob here is an [example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-jdbc-blob).

Comment: Base64 approach of serving images is terribly inefficient at all levels. Do not recommend this to starters.